# Switch function not doing what I want

Tags: matlab, switch-statement

I wrote a simple program to help evaluate a probability problem. During 10 hours of the day, the probability of a certain event is different than for the rest of the day. To account for this , i'm trying to use the switch function but it's not working. The code is the following (I'm using MATLAB):

```
clear all
status = 0;      %0 ventilador apagat, 1 encès.
nsim = 10000;
enceses = 0;
runtime = 0;
sampletime = 0;
minute = 0;
while (runtime < 10000 || enceses < 18000)
    r = rand;
    switch minute
        case minute < 601
            if (r < 0.1642)
                status = 0;
            else
                runtime = runtime + 5/60;
                if status == 0
                    status = 1;
                    enceses = enceses + 1;
                else
                end
            end
            sampletime = sampletime + 5/60;
            minute = minute + 5;
        case minute > 600
            if (r < 0.801)
                status = 0;
            else
                runtime = runtime + 5/60;
                if status == 0
                    status = 1;
                    enceses = enceses + 1;
                else
                end
            end
            sampletime = sampletime + 5/60;
            minute = minute + 5;
            if minute == 1440
                minute = 0;
            end
    end
end
enceses
runtime
sampletime
```

nsim does nothing for the moment

I analyzed the execution step by step and found that in the first loop the switch works as intended and goes into the first case but after that it enters neither, if i put an otherwise print ("error"), it just prints out a bunch of errors.

Comment: That is not how a `switch` statement works. Each `case` will be compared to a static value. You cannot put `conditions` (like a>b) in the `case` line. If you want to use `conditions` you have to use an `if ... ` statement.

Answer (score 0):

For your application, instead of `switch-case`, you can use `if`-`elseif`-`end` statements as follows:

```
if minute < 600
   <some statements>
elseif minute >= 600
   <another statements>
end
```